# How to hide an unavoidable error message in Python, but keep eventual output?

Tags: python, logging, hide, message, speech

So I'm playing around with the speech recognition python software:

```
#! /usr/bin/python                                                   
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:                # use the default  microphone as the audio source
    audio = r.listen(source)                   # listen for the first phrase and extract it into audio data

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
except LookupError:                            # speech is unintelligible
    print("Could not understand audio")
```

Now, this works surprisingly well and is extremely fun to fool around with, but unfortunately on some versions of Ubuntu there's an unavoidable and unappealing bluetooth error message that prints about 6 times everytime that   r.listen(source) is run.

Is there a way to hide that rubbish output from r.listen(source) and still have my print statements bellow work???

Comment: What does the error message look like? It is probably a driver that is writing that to standard error or similar, having the exact error message might help us confirm this.

Comment: Not really familiar with speech recognition but is there any you could do `while audio = your_error_text or not audio:  audio = r.listen(source)`

Comment: Do the messages look like `ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1613:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)` perhaps?

Comment: yes actually, the site I was on suggested that the only thing to do was to ignore this